# UITableViewCell layoutSubViews: why don't I get animation?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uikit

I always thought that whatever changes I perform in `layoutSubViews:` is done animated?
Is this incorrect information?
In my case I'm inheriting from a `UITableViewCell`.
The controller gets informed that the user wants to enlarge the cells, so I first use a `UITableView` animation block to increase row height. The height increases smoothly animated to the new height.

Then I loop my visible cells, set a flag and call `setNeedsLayout:`
The cells indeed layout and adust the content to the new height but without animation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that is not correct, the default approach for layoutSubviews will not be performed animated, it is up to you to begin / commit an animation block or use the blocks animation feature.

Comment: Ah. Okay. Looks like I got confused. And what about changes to the frame of a UIView? That should be animated if within an animation block, correct?

Comment: Yes absolutely, only within an animation block. You can change some of the layer properties (the underlying Core Animation stuff) which will animate but the higher level UIKit properties will need to be wrapped up in animation blocks.

Comment: I'm puzzled. Some of my subviews animate, others not (Monotouch code, but you should get the point). All code from layoutSubviews. This one animates fine: lblDmoName.Frame = new RectangleF (this.IconView.Frame.Right + 5, 10, this.oContentSubView.Bounds.Width - 50, 18);
The code one line below does not animate: btnFavorite.Center = new PointF (this.oContentSubView.Bounds.Width - 70, this.oContentSubView.Bounds.Height / 2);.
I also notice that shrinking the bounds of UIImageView animates, while growing it does not. What the heck am I doing wrong?

Comment: Oh well, ignore...I found it...the height of the cell was not updated correctly. *duh*